# Attempting to start Windows Defender fails with error code 577

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender

I'm trying to enable Windows Defender on a few Windows machines I manage. When first configured the machines had all the related group policies for Windows Defender turned off, so I created a small script that creates and sets the following registry keys:

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Microsoft/Windows Defender/AllowFastServiceStartup" 
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Microsoft/Windows Defender/DisableAntiSpyware"
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Microsoft/Windows Defender/DisableAntivirus" 
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Microsoft/Windows Defender/Real-Time Protection"
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Microsoft/Windows Defender/ServiceKeepAlive" 
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Microsoft/Windows Defender/UX Configuration/Notification_Suppress"
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Microsoft/Windows Defender/UX Configuration/UILockDown" 
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Policies/Microsoft/Windows Defender/Scan/CheckForSignatureBeforeRunningScan"
```

Setting the various values of the keys to what I desire.

I tried to start the service manually after doing so but I get the following error:

`Error 577: Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file.`

I have read online that this could be attributed to another av software being present. The only one my machines had was clamscan, which has been removed.

I am perplexed as to why this is happening. Has anyone any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: I'm assuming you rebooted after removing clamscan?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender

DisableAntiVirus and set its data to 0

DisableAntiSpyware and set its data to 0

Do the same for:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender

Exit and restart, see if Defender can start now